# Fourier-type decomposition for a weakly stationary process

Tags: stochastic-processes, harmonic-analysis, signal-processing, positive-definite, stationary-processes

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process#Motivation),

> there exists a stochastic process $\omega _{\xi }$ with orthogonal
> increments such that, for all $t$,
> the weakly stationary process $X_t = \int e^{- 2 \pi i \lambda \cdot t} \, d \omega_\lambda,$

It is deducted by applying [Bochner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner%27s_theorem) on the autocovariance function which is [positive-definite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_function). However, I don't understand how the stationary process could also be regarded as a Fourier-transform.

Still from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process#Motivation),

> By the positive definiteness of the autocovariance function, it
> follows from Bochner's theorem that there exists a positive measure $
> > \mu $ on the real line such that $H$ is isomorphic to the Hilbert
> subspace of $L^2(μ)$ generated by $e^{−2πiξ⋅t}$. This then gives the
> following Fourier-type decomposition for a continuous time stationary
> stochastic process.

> The same result holds for a discrete-time stationary process, with the spectral measure now defined on the unit circle.

Could someone explain it with more details?